# How to not generate .gz file in the war build with Grails 3.3.2

Tags: javascript, security, grails, gzip

My application is build with Grails 3.3.2 and my application contains some javascript files (.js)

When I build my application (*grails prod war*), grails, beside generating digested version js files, still generate another gzip version jacascript files like below:

[image]

And these .gz files seem to lead CWE 200 security issue:

> Web Server Misconfiguration: Unprotected File ( 11405 )
>
> Webinspect has detected an archive file with the .gz extension on the
> target server. The severity of the threats posed by the web-accessible
> backup files depends on the sensitivity of the information stored in
> original document. Based on that information, an attacker can gain
> sensitive information about the site architecture, database and
> network access credential details, encryption keys, and so forth from
> these files. The attacker can use information obtained to craft
> precise targeted attacks, which may not otherwise be feasible, against
> the application.

[image]

I think maybe I should not generate those .gz files. But how to let Grails not grnerate those .gz files ?

I have tried below config in my build.gradle but in vain.

```
assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    enableGzip = false
}
```

Comment: Have you done a full clean since adding enableGzip = false?  It may just be that the files are still there after having been generated much earlier.

Comment: @Daniel , thanks. It works

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this later, the answer was:

- assets { enableGzip = false } as shown in the question
- clean the project to remove any previously created gz files